# signed long - python random number generator

Tags: python

I am trying to generate span id based on `Comcast` money trace specification.

https://github.com/Comcast/money/wiki

`span-id` should be `signed long int` representation

Following are queries

1. Does "long int" represents 64 bit or 32 bit
2. I used following function to generate 'span-id' but parser used in central server failed saying "out of range of long (-9223372036854775808 - 9223372036854775807)"

`random.getrandbits(64);`

I am confused whether long int should be `32 bit` or `64 bit` ?

Comment: According to the error the server gives you, the long is a 64bit integer with sign. (You can just to the log2 of the maximum and approximate to the nearest power of 2)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it's telling you the range tells you that it's a 64 bit integer.
[-9223372036854775808, 9223372036854775807] = [-2^63, 2^63-1]

`getrandbits` doesn't produce a signed int though. I.e. you're creating integers between 0 and 18446744073709551616.

Try `getrandbits(64) - 2**63`

Comment: getrandbits(64) - 2**63 ==> Always gives negative value as it is subtracted from bigger value. I am looking for signed long random number generation which is 64bit long. If I give "getrandbits(63)", my server is not throwing error

Comment: In case of Java, long refers to 64bit signed value and it takes                                             -(2^63) to (2^63)-1.

Comment: It absolutely does not: `x = [getrandbits(64) - 2**63 for _ in range(10)]` gives me `[-7995997991646516456L, -6383526809044592462L, 6003662461365090516L, -789142758957436074L, 7464986895865743721L, -4020795961443839225L, 8155120521167465149L, -4392579242065832655L, -4528630808698508870L, 1266825288368309192L]`

Comment: thanks..I misunderstood. Since 2**63 is used, max value of 64 bit will produce positive output

Answer (score 0):

Some one can please correct me if understanding is wrong

Always "random.getrandombits(64)" will produce an output

unsigned 64bit number ( 0 to 2**64 -1)

Possible solution is to produce signed long int (-(2^63) to (2^63)-1)

random.getrandombits(64) - 2**63

Thanks @Batman